# Magento 2 - PayPal Express Checkout duplicate invoice id

Tags: magento2, paypal, payment, paypal-express

When I checkout using **PayPal express checkout**, it returns an error message

> PayPal gateway has rejected request. Payment has already been made for this InvoiceID (#10412: Duplicate invoice)

I have tried to reset everything but still get the same error.

How to solve this issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is because the same Invoice ID has been submitted to the same PayPal business account. This always happens on dev server as the Invoice ID always reset due to re-installation.

## Workaround - Allow Duplicate Invoice

Profile > Payment Receiving Preferences

[image]

Block accidental payments > allow multiple payments per invoice ID

[image]

Comment: you have any idea where this now is on the newer paypal designs?

Comment: @Owen https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/businessprofile/settings -> My selling preferences -> Block Payments

Comment: Another option is to use a different invoice & order prefix on development, such as "DEV-XXXXX" to avoid this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Updating in Feb '21
PayPal account > Settings (right top gear symbol) > Seller tools (last option on menu) > scroll down to Payment Preferences > Block Accidental Payments

Answer (score 0):

Generally this occurs when you have two copies of site, one is staging and one is LIVE where in LIVE site, the order is getting placed through PayPal so invoice number is getting increased and recorded accordingly in PayPal account.

Now in your staging, your order number and invoice number are generally very few and lower than the actual so when you set your LIVE Paypal credentials in your staging and when you try to place real order, staging tries to generate the invoice number as per staging series where this number is already generated by LIVE and recorded in PayPal dashboard and hence this error occurs

for quick fix, it is advisable to change your order number, invoice number, shipment and credit memo series from 100000XXXX to 20000XXXX this can be done by few free extensions as well