# Magento 2: PayPal gateway has rejected request. Payment has already been made for this InvoiceID

Tags: magento2, paypal, invoice, payment

I'm using Paypal Sandbox Account. I'm facing below issue

```
[2017-03-15 03:32:20] main.CRITICAL: Exception message: PayPal gateway has rejected request. Payment has already been made for this InvoiceID (#10412: Duplicate invoice).
Trace: #0 D:\wamp\www\magento\vendor\magento\framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer.php(89): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory->createObject('Magento\\Framewo...', Array)
#1 D:\wamp\www\magento\vendor\magento\framework\ObjectManager\ObjectManager.php(57): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer->create('Magento\\Framewo...', Array)
#2 D:\wamp\www\magento\var\generation\Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedExceptionFactory.php(43): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\ObjectManager->create('\\Magento\\Framew...', Array)
```

Answer (score 2):

By default Paypal does not allow you to put through the same invoice number twice. This can happen when you use the same credentials across multiple different Magento sites (even across a local environment and your staging environment)

You can change this behaviour in Paypal under Your Profile > Selling Tools > Block payments
and then change the setting for Block accidental Payments to
`"No, allow multiple payments per invoice ID"`

[image: block accidental payments]

For me the direct link to the relevant settings is
https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/customerprofileweb?cmd=_profile-pref

Comment: Thank you so much @kristof fooman it is working perfect for me....

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/368890/55221